# How do you set Image.Source in Silverlight(Code behind)

Tags: silverlight

I am dynamically generating an image through code-behind in Silverlight and apparently the image source doesn't accept a string or Uri as a path.

How can I set the source?

Comment: This took me a little while to figure out too.  Guantam's answer looks like what I used.

Comment: I had to change it a bit though, it worked without including the namespace in the path

Answer (score 54, accepted):

How do you mean it won't accept a string as source?

Are you not able to do this?

Or are you saying your image is in memory and you don't know how to reference it?

```
this.MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyNameSpace;images/someimage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Doesnt accept string i meant for example: MyImage.Source  = "/MyNameSpace;images/someimage.png" like in asp.net

Comment: my project needs to append "components": this.MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyNameSpace;components/images/someimage.png", UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 6):

```
// create a new image
Image image = new Image();

// better to keep this in a global config singleton
string hostName = Application.Current.Host.Source.Host;                   
if (Application.Current.Host.Source.Port != 80)
    hostName += ":" + Application.Current.Host.Source.Port;

// set the image source
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://" + hostName + "/image111.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: no need to go for HTTP protocol. just use local resource is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to replace the following to get the solution work:

```
this.MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyNameSpace;components/images/someimage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

MyNameSpace did not work for me, but the ExecutingAssemblyName did, so:

```
Dim tmp As String() = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName.Split(","c)
Dim path As String = "/" & tmp(0) & ";component/images/"
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path & "someImage.png"))
```