# Image problem in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, image

Greetings

**Problem**

When i'm trying to add images to my silverlight project I get the error: `"AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR"`.

**Recreate**

I create a new silverlight 4 project without a web part. So I only get MyApplication.

In MyApplication I add a map called "Images" and in that map I add a few images. Egg.png, Chicken.png.

Now I wish to load these images to my silverlight project. In the mainpage.xaml I place:
 `<Image Source="/Images/Egg.png" />` but this does't load.

So I try it from code behind:

```
var imag = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Images\Egg.png", UriKind.Relative));
imag.ImageFailed += (s, ea) =>
{
    throw new Exception(ea.ErrorException.Message);
};
```

This however keeps throwing the above error nomather what I try.

The images are set as a resource and "Do Not Copy".

1. What am I doing wrong??
2. How can I make the images work?

**[Edit]**

After comments I noticed the image is loading in the original project.

But I have a user control in a different project to which I send the image. From there the loading still fails.

How can I fix this?
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Is the Build Action set to Resource or Content? In C# it should be `new Uri(@"/Images/Egg.png", UriKind.Relative)`.

Comment: Resource as said above. "The images are set as a **Resource** and 'Do Not Copy'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a terrible generic error message but I believe the problem may simply be that the files can't be found. When you add items to your Silverlight project they don't get copied out to the `ClientBin` folder of the hosting site (even on build, regardless of `Copy to output directory` settings because this only dictates what makes it to the current project's `bin` folder)  - you'll need to copy these manually (or eventually use a post-build step), that is:

- Copy required resources yourself from the Silverlight project to the hosting website's `ClientBin` folder, alongside the `.xap` file.

**Update**:

So, there's no website part of the solution, are the resources making it to the `bin` folder of the Silverlight project itself? If not, try this:

- Set the images `BuildAction` to `Content`
- Set `Copy to output directory` to `Copy Always`, or `Copy if newer`

Comment: Since it's a client only project, there is not clientbin. ClientBin is website only IIRC

Comment: OK - so you're running it from a test page in the `bin` folder of the Silverlight project? Are the resources available in _that_ folder?

Comment: Yes the resources are in the bin of the silverlight project.
"Project/Bin/Debug/Images" to be exact

Answer (score 0):

When your XAML is parsed:

```
<Image Source="/Images/Egg.png" />
```

The URI is converted into a suitable URI for locating your image. If you set the source in code-behind you have to do this conversion yourself. The URI is of this format:

```
/MyNameSpace;Images/Egg.png
```

See this related question:

[How do you set Image.Source in Silverlight(Code behind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577502/how-do-you-set-image-source-in-silverlightcode-behind)

Comment: Noticed the images works properly untill I send it to a different project. See edited question please