# How to get XML to TextBlocks and an Image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

So I have a Windows Phone C# application in which I want to get a google weather api xml file located here: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=[insert zip code here] and get the current weather info.  Well I want to display the image located in the xml file and I want to, based on the image, display a background image.  How would I do that? 
Also, I don't want to use a listbox for it because it won't let me resize the image to full screen.

Comment: You need to learn here how to parse an XML file :http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/android-to-wp7-chapter-7-xml-parsing-in-windows-phone-7-and-android

Answer (score 0):

You are asking rather a lot in your question, so here are some pointers rather than a complete answer.

1. Use Linq to XML to analyse the returned XML, using the `XDocument.Parse` method
2. Locate the images using Linq to XML, doc.Descendants("icon") will find all the icon elements, you can then iterate over them and extract the data attribute.
3. Create an ImageBrush for your background, setting its source to the URL of the image you require. There are numerous blog posts / SO questions that show you how to handle images in code-behind. For example:

[How do you set Image.Source in Silverlight(Code behind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577502/how-do-you-set-image-source-in-silverlightcode-behind)

This should get you started. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and ask a specific question.